# Is there a way to create an Half Doughnut Chart with circle in ECharts?

Tags: echarts

I would like to create a chart like this in ECharts:

[image]

Is there a way? Anyone have any other ideas?

I tried using option itemStyle.borderRadius an example from the ECharts page, but it was not the result I expected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two offical examples which come close to what you want:

1. [Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-half-donut): using a [pie series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-pie), but i dont think its possible to make the border round and overlapping if that is a requirement
2. [Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=gauge-multi-title): using a [gauge series](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-gauge), should fit your needs if adjusted a little (set `startAngle` / `endAngle` and remove labels)

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=gauge-multi-title&code=MYewdgzgLgBA5gQwK5wKYBEFQTAvDAbQCgYYBvE0mANwQBslUAuGADgAYAaS0sBAW2YwA5AHEQIACbDuVGAEsoqfgGUoATzpCyoOiABOLYXXlwAFlABGDVMIC-sqlEVaWFOaRAAzLxFRQAYVQwJUNCYQBaABZ2AFIZETjhAF0eGAc0yX8EeTo3NM8fP0Dg0JYCSJj4zhEARgBWeNS5O0oM0ncqWhsWAE5ex14BIWEAIX9QmTTFZTVNbV0DIzh9VGD7QZhnKFdyAphvX38gkNQwiqSa4STmqnaqLOxc_I8DouPSs_Lr6rrGlLSrVI906pG6jBY9S4aT4giMAAUzl5UMAoFM5DNVBpdjoQHowsIAA5IfSErQbNLbHH7Q7FE5lcJVBI_AEtTaPHJ5PavWkfU7nYRMq4NJqAtpEZIAbiIIEJznAeG5MD8-nkqAg5TSoKc6kJI0QKFsm1I0AQ-igAEEwHBdrUOMaYMFJFabUIAMwANmhr0J-hAK3VGqVrwgZhAAHcWFB9IwHZ5qGc6AhCVGY6g4zA_UgwJIAsnU7H9qRw_JJFAzCx7ft7nJCSB5PyXq9lWHIzAvPQ_NWHZIsAgWAa0JhsA6EAAPeQQAAyDe0oYjLA7dD8Nao48nU4QllQXLI87bS5Xo4nEAAKvJgABrNz7xed1Crk1kxQzsBz1t35cPzZAmCpOySkAA) is the gauge example adjusted to reflect more closely what is shown in your image:

```js
const gaugeData = [
  {
    value: 80,
    name: 'Good',
    itemStyle: {color: 'lightblue'},
    title: {
      offsetCenter: ['-40%', '0%']
    },
    detail: {
      offsetCenter: ['-40%', '15%']
    }
  },
  {
    value: 99,
    name: 'Better',
    itemStyle: {color: 'green'},
    title: {
      offsetCenter: ['0%', '0%']
    },
    detail: {
      offsetCenter: ['0%', '15%']
    }
  },
  {
    value: 50,
    name: 'Perfect',
    itemStyle: {color: 'purple'},
    title: {
      offsetCenter: ['40%', '0%']
    },
    detail: {
      offsetCenter: ['40%', '15%']
    }
  }
];
option = {
  series: [
    {
      type: 'gauge',
      startAngle: 180,
      endAngle: 360,
      progress: {
        show: true,
        overlap: true,
        roundCap: true,
        width: 80,
      },
      pointer: {
        show: false
      },
      data: gaugeData,
      axisLine: {show: false},
      axisLabel: {show: false},
      axisTick: {show: false},
      splitLine: {show: false},
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was waiting for